# I'm stuck with Youtube's new experimental ui (found non-flash solution)

Tags: firefox, youtube, user-interface

For a long time Youtube has this new experimental ui: 
http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/04/12/youtubes-experimental-web-player-interface-can-be-activated-using-a-chrome-extension/
Which can be turned on by setting a cookie. This has been turning on for me at random times over the past year or so, but usually I can clear my cookies and it is back to normal.

Now, it changed to the new ui, I cleared the cookies, it went back to normal, and then it changed again to the new ui. And I can't turn it off now.

I've tried:

- clearing my cookies
- turning off all my userscripts
- using chrome instead of firefox
- using internet explorer
- Signing in with a different account
- Signing out completely

It just doesn't go away, what can I do about this? I can't stand the transparency, and the animations.

I've made a userscript to fix this, but it seems that this question is 'put on hold', so I can't post it as an answer.

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/11485-youtube-new-ui-fix

Comment: Have you considered it may no longer be experimental?

Comment: Just like that? Not even a message saying "hi, we changed the ui again and it is horrible."?

Comment: They are constantly making changes to the site.  They're not going to send you message every time they make a change.  They just happened to make one that you didn't like.

Comment: I'm seeing the comments on certain videos already... Still, the question remains: how to revert? Also, **one** change I didn't like? They have never made a change I don't dislike.

Comment: It's not an experiment anymore.

Comment: @user886079 - You can't.  The interface has changed.  Why do we have a question on YouTube on Superuser anyways?

Comment: For Firefox, there are add-ons such as the *YouTube Video Flash Player*, which directs YouTube to use either the HTML5 or Flash interface. Perhaps that would help.

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't sure where to post something like this, any ideas where it would fit better? There doesn't seem to be a stackexchange for ui issues. Also there's a chance someone will find a fix for this (userscript?), and in any case maybe someone at youtube will see this and maybe do something? (wishful thinking) And I'll try that YouTube Video Flash Player, thanks DrMoishe Pippik.

Comment: It's unlikely anyone a google will change the interface, they tested it, with the intention of rolling it out

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That actually worked, old ui, flash (no speed options; but w/e). You should post that as an answer (there might be a better answers in the future, but for now, it's fine). Consider your comment to be upvoted (which I can't actually do at my reputation?).

Comment: @Ramhound I wonder how they actually test that... Do they just make a new ui that they think is better? Or do they grab fifty people from the street and ask them if they like it? Can I be a tester?

Comment: What do you mean?  They allowed people to use the new interface by choice, they took feedback, then rolled it out to everyone after a period of time

Comment: What feedback? I never saw any "i like/dislike this ui" button or a feedback button, or a poll asking if the new ui is good or not. They don't have a forum, a uservoice, or anything similar to that. They don't even seem to have an official youtube channel.

Comment: They probably get their feedback through the Google Product Forums and look what was posted today: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/taswo8KkN1E Also, there is an official [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube) and [Google channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/Google).

Comment: @user886079 - You should post the script as an answer instead of modifying your question to include the answer.

Comment: I would do that, if I could. But I don't see a "post your answer" button anywhere, probably because of the "on hold" situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox, there are add-ons such as the [YouTube Video Flash Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/), which directs YouTube to use either the HTML5 or Flash interface. Perhaps that would help.

P.S. Thanks for feedback, @user886079... glad it works!